# does pthread_mutex_recursive attribute will affect openssl

Tags: openssl

I need a clarification in below problem.

Problem:
I am writing a wrapper to use openssl in which I am locking (mutex) and adding certificate information to openssl store using `X509_STORE_add_cert()` function and also doing some more steps followed by this.

Here my problem is, to update openssl store, I have locked the whole operation before calling `X509_STORE_add_cert()` and with in this function once again the same lock is used to actually update the openssl store. So, I have used `pthread_mutex_recursive` attribute for mutex and my code works fine.

But, since I am initializing array of global mutex list with `pthread_mutex_recursive`, will it affect the other openssl clients in the system?

Kindly reply and help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: OpenSSL expects you to configure locks for it's internal usage. It is not clear from your question as to how and why are you using the same lock to protect X509_STORE_add_cert() function call. Please post some details and code.

Comment: Hi, I actually protecting the below section

Comment: Hi, I actually protecting the below section
/* Lock X509_STORE! Needed to ensure that we can replace the OpenSSL store content while connections are running/renegotiating! */
CRYPTO_w_lock(CRYPTO_LOCK_X509_STORE);

for (i = 0; i < sk_X509_INFO_num(hStore)->x509infos); i++)
{
   *** get store info ***
   if (X509_STORE_add_cert(openSslStore, tempInfo->x509))
   {
      *** do some work ***
   }
if (X509_STORE_add_crl(openSslStore, tempInfo->crl))
{
   *** do some work ***
}
}
X509_STORE_set_flags(openSslStore, CheckFlags);

CRYPTO_w_unlock(CRYPTO_LOCK_X509_STORE);

Comment: Any information on this will be really helpful.